# find a linear transformation,

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find a linear transformation  $$T:\mathcal{P}_3\rightarrow\mathcal{P}_3 $$ such that

$$ker(T)=\{p\in\mathcal{P}_3: p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \text{ and } 2a_1-3a_2=0\}$$

Find a basis for the kernel and image. Check that the kernel and image theorem is satisfied.

I found a linear transformation
$T : \mathcal{P}_3 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_3$ defined as:

$$
T(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3) = a_0 + a_1x + \frac{2}{3}a_1x^2 + a_3x^3
$$
Is this correct?
But I can't find a base for the kernel and the image, can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean the rank-nullity theorem instead of the kernel image theorem?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: $T(1 + x^3)  = 1 + x^3 \neq 0$, but satisfies $2a_1 - 3a_2=0$, so your function is not correct

Comment: What about $$T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3)=(2a_1-3a_2)q(x)$$ where $q$ is a fixed nonzero polynomial of degree less than or equal $3$ ? For example $q(x)=1.$